# How to print a duplicate once in an array WITHOUT map or arraylist

Tags: java, arrays

I am creating a program where I am importing a .dat file and printing the values on the command prompt in order it is read. No problems there. The only thing is I cannot figure out the code to only print certain variables once.

```
import java.io.*;               
import java.util.Scanner;       

public class program4
{
    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException
    {
        double [] values;               //creating array called values
        values = new double [40];       //establishing array that has 40 cells
        int k;                          //creating counter integer

        Scanner InputFile = new Scanner( new FileReader("temp.dat"));       

        k = 0;

        while (InputFile.hasNextDouble())   //read values from file using ascending while loop
        {
            values[k] = InputFile.nextDouble();                             
            k++;
        }

        for (k = 0 ; k < values.length ; k++)
            System.out.println(values[k]);

        InputFile.close();
    }
}
```

Where is the best place to initialize the code for getting rid of the duplicates that the .dat file contains?

Comment: Curiosity: Why won't you use a map or arraylist?

Comment: We have not  yet covered it in my class (intro level comp sci) and my professor does not want us to use stuff he did not teach

Comment: then you're just going to have to iterate through the array everytime before you print

Comment: One approach is to sort the array first and then search.

Comment: But can you use a `Set`?

Comment: no we cannot use a    Set

Comment: Well then it's easy, isn't it? Add it to your array if it doesn't exist yet and print it out right away or at the end. There's only one place to check whether it is already inside your datastructure and that's *after reading*, *before adding to the array* and *before printing*.

Comment: Another issue is that an array of `double` is initialized to all 0s when created.  If you read a 0 from your .dat file, you'll need to make sure you don't accidentally check for duplication past the point where you've put values into your array.

Comment: Write your own set implementation using what you're allowed to use, or loop over the array in a O(n^2) way to detect the duplicates. By the way, this code will get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if there are ever more than 40 doubles in the file.

Comment: Are there min and max values for the values in the .dat file?  e.g. 0 <= x <= 40?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a method that checks if a value exists more than once in the array

```
boolean isDuplicate(double x, double[] array, int checkUpTo){
    numOfOccurencies = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <= checkUpTo; i++)
        if(x == array[i])
            numOfOccurencies++;
    return(numOfOccurencies > 1)? true : false;
}
```

and then

```
for (k = 0 ; k < values.length ; k++)
    if(!isDuplicate(values[k], values, k)
            System.out.println(values[k]);
```

So every time you try to print a double from the array you check up to that index if the double appears more than once. That way you guarantee than you will print everything at least once. for example if you have a value appear at index 2 and index 4 then you check first at index 2 and since you check up to that index the value is not duplicate and gets printed. After that you check up to 4 and find the second occurrance so value is not printed.

Hope this helps

EDIT: i was assuming that you only want to get rid of duplicates when you print. If you dont want to store duplicate values you need something similar:

```
boolean isDuplicate(double x, double[] array){
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        if array[i] == x
            return true;
    return false;
}

while (InputFile.hasNextDouble())   //read values from file using ascending while loop
        {
            double temp = InputFile.nextDouble();
            if(!isDuplicate(temp, values){
                values[k] = temp
                k++;
            }


        }

        for (k = 0 ; k < values.length ; k++)
            System.out.println(values[k]);
```

Comment: in the  boolean you so kindly posted (ty btw =D) you have if array[i] == x Where does the x come? Would it be the double mentioned as a perimeter and would this be double temp you have in the while statement?

Comment: Yes the x is the parameter `double x`. Allthough i just noticed i don't pass the array as well when i am calling the isDuplicate method. I edited the answer. So this is correct `if(!isDuplicate(temp, values)` etc

Comment: last question =P while compiling it is showing an error saying "reached the end while parsing" Does that mean I have to add a return in somewhere else as well?

Comment: Please check if you have any unclosed `{`  . I also have edited the answer one last time. Use the new one

Comment: I finally have all of that done. However now it is saying I cannot run boolean isDuplicate in a static method. So I switched my main method to non static but then an error comes up for that saying it needs to be static. Last question I promise lol

Comment: Add `static` in front of any method you are calling inside your `main` method. 
For example 
`static boolean isDuplicate(double x, double[] array){...}` etc

Answer (score 0):

The simplest modification to your program would be to modify your while loop to not store duplicates, by checking through the values you have already stored:

```
    while (InputFile.hasNextDouble())   //read values from file using ascending while loop
    {
        double nextValue = InputFile.nextDouble();

        // check to see if next value has already been stored
        boolean duplicate = false;
        for (int i=0; i<k; i++) {
            if (nextValue == values[i]) {
                duplicate = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        // only store values if they have not already been read
        if (!duplicate) {
            values[k] = nextValue;
            k++;
        }
    }
```

You might also want to modify your print statement to only print the array up to the index to which you have written values (`k`):

```
    for (int i = 0 ; i < k ; i++) {
        System.out.println(values[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to sort the array once it is built and check if it has duplicate value.

Of course you can brute force it and loop the entire array every time you add an item, but this is terribly inefficient. The solution below is also equally inefficient to start with, but has opportunities for optimization.

I am deliberately avoiding to give code because I assume you want to learn and not just copy-paste.

Once you have the array `values` populated (so, after your `while` loop), sort the array. You probably already know how to sort an array from previous exercises, but if you don't, [bubble sort](http://mathbits.com/MathBits/Java/arrays/Bubble.htm) is the easiest to learn (and the worst in performance).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266611/how-to-make-bubble-sort-in-java-to-output-the-sorted-numbers#answer-16266686) for a simple bubble sort implementation.

```
function bubbleSort:
    //values is your array
    //length is the length of values
    loop i from 0 to length - 1
        loop j from i+1 to length - 1
            if values[i] > values[j]
                swap values[i] and values[j]
            end if
        end loop
    end loop
end function
```

Once you have a sorted array, loop through it and check if the current element is the same as the previous element. If it is, then it is a duplicate.

```
function removeDuplicates:
//values is your array
//non_duplicate_array is another array with only non duplicate values
loop from 1 to size-1 //and not from 0, because we are comparing 
                      //an element with the previous and 
                      //the element at 0 does not have a previous element
    if values[i] == values[i-1]
        //duplicate!
    else
        add element to non_duplicate_array.
    end if
end loop
```

So we have:

- populate array (code that you already have)
- sort
- search and remove duplicates

One optimization that you can build is to ensure that the sorting itself has duplicate elimination:

This is the innermost loop in the bubble sort above:

```
loop j from i+1 to length - 1
    if values[i] > values[j]
        swap values[i] and values[j]
    end if
end loop
```

Here instead of swapping the values, you can add the values to another array, and while doing so, do only the non duplicates:

```
function bubbleSort:
    //values is your array
    //length is the length of values
    //non_duplicate_array is another array that will eventually have
    //sorted non duplicate values
    loop i from 0 to length - 1
        loop j from i+1 to length - 1
            if values[i] != values[j]
                if values[i] > values[j]
                    add values[j] to non_duplicate_array 
                else
                    add values[i] to non_duplicate_array 
                end if
            end if
        end loop
    end loop
end function
```

The sort is bubble sort, so it is very [inefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Performance), especially because of the nested loop. But you can replace that with [merge sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727030/mergesort-in-java#answer-13727872) or quick sort that are [far more efficient](http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/ComparisonSort.html). And you can adapt the merge or quick sort algorithms so that they remove duplicates.

This works only if you are ok with the output array being sorted. Otherwise you need to brute force it, as in @xgeorgekx's answer. Or use a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html).

Edit:

Just so that you understand why you see a lot of recommendations for set, the following is all that is needed with a `Set`:

```
   Set valueSet = new HashSet<Double>();
   ...
   ...
    while (InputFile.hasNextDouble())
    {
        valueSet.add(InputFile.nextDouble());
    }
```

That's it. The set will have only non-duplicate values. But then you will not learn programming :-) .