# How to sort 2D array(int) without converting it into 1D array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

How can I sort 2d array without converting it into 1d array.
This is what I have done -

private int[][] data2D = {{1,2,3},{6,8},{3,2,5,2}};

```
private void sortCustom(){

    int totalElements = 0;

    // calculating total elements
    for(int[] i : data2D){
        totalElements = totalElements+i.length;
    }


    int[] data1D = new int[totalElements];
    int m = 0 ;
    // converting 2D data into 1D
    for(int i=0 ; i<data2D.length ; i++ ){
        for(int j=0 ; j<data2D[i].length ; j++){
            data1D[m++] = data2D[i][j];
        }
    }

    // sorting data 
    Arrays.sort(data1D);

    //converting 1D data into 2D
    int n=0;
    for(int i=0 ; i<data2D.length ; i++){
        for(int j=0 ; j<data2D[i].length ; j++){
            data2D[i][j] = data1D[n++];
        }
    }

    // print sorted data 
    for(int i=0 ; i<data2D.length ; i++){
        for(int j=0 ; j<data2D[i].length ; j++){
            System.out.print(data2D[i][j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

output :
 
1 2 2
 
2 3 
3 5 6 8

As you can see I am able to sort 2d array after converting it into 1d. My question is how can I sort 2d array without converting it into 1d array?

I want to short all the values , not row by row

Comment: What you've done can be applied for 2D, 3D or nD as well. You bubble sort each n-dimension. This can even be done independent of how many dimensions you have.

You can also take a look at [Radix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) to learn how it does, as the idea is somewhat similiar.

Comment: A 2D array is just an array of arrays. Iterate through your arrays and sort them.

Comment: If you look at his input and output though, it appears that he wants to sort all of the values, not just sort each individual array.

Comment: yes exactly , I want to sort all the values else I would have treated each item as one array

Answer (score 1):

You can use [bubble sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266611/how-to-make-bubble-sort-in-java-to-output-the-sorted-numbers), for a simple array you must use 2 nested `for-loops`, so for a 2d array you must use 3 nested `for-loops`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < data2D.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < data2D[0].length; j++){
        for(int k = 0; k < data2D[j].length; k++){
            if(data2D[i][k]>data2D[i][k+1]){
                int temp = data2D[i][k];
                data2D[i][k] = data2D[i][k+1];
                data2D[i][k+1] = temp;
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use sorting(bubblesort, quicksort) algorithms. Choose for your need, if your data is small it does not matter at all. Otherwise choose O(nlogn) algorithms

Answer (score 0):

Just try something like this:

Use Overloaded Arrays#Sort(T[] a, Comparator c) which takes Comparator as the second argument.

```
double[][] array= {
{1, 5},
{13, 1.55},
{12, 100.6},
{12.1, .85} };

java.util.Arrays.sort(array, new java.util.Comparator<double[]>() {
   public int compare(double[] a, double[] b) {
       return Double.compare(a[0], b[0]);
   }
});
```